# Making a java project, using MongoDB, run on remote server (ssh)

Tags: java, mongodb, ssh, jar, war

I'm trying to make a java project run on a remote server. 
I've used Maven and the project uses a Mongo database. I've got access to a home directory on a remote web server. MongoDB, Tomcat and java are installed so the only thing I have to do is to transfer my Mongo Database and my project and making this all work and run.

However, I'm new to all this and I've got no clue in how to do this. I also can't find anything online on how to archieve this.

How would I go about doing this via SSH?

**Additional info:**

My project includes:

- .js files
- .java files
- .html files

1 main java class which should run constantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you are new for this kind of development, (actually it is more about deployment so popular tag DEVOPS anyway...) take it easy so use your application server and database in the same machine(which is not a suggested way for large systems).

- ***Step 1*** For ssh you need to create key read this document and [create a key](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)
- ***Step 2*** Make a ssh connection to your remote machine like

  ssh username@yourIp

it will ask a password enter the password which is given by you when creating the SSH key.

- ***Step 3*** Install Mongo DB, Maven, Tomcat, Java to your remote machine.
- ***Step 4*** Copy your war to under remote machine webapps

  ## Secure Copy war to remote machine

  scp -vC  ~/.m2/repository/com/foo/Example/foo.war   username@yourIp:/home/Development/tomcat/webapps
  echo "Copy to server"
- ***Step 5*** Run tomcat server Go to tomcat/bin directory run startup.sh

  /tomcat/bin/startup.sh